# Does Kafka save messages in binary with AVRO, JSON shema or protobuf?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Messages I'm trying to push into Kafka is too big so I used AVRO in order to make them binary, but implementation from code perspective is kind of bad and overcomplicated (I need to have schema files .avsc,maven plugin to generate avro classes). And it looks like JSON schema is much better option, because you just need some annotations on POJO and it should just work(looks more something like Jackson).

The question is: AVRO vs JSON schema vs Protobuf, what is message size difference? If I will use JSON schema will it be saved in binary inside kafka just like AVRO? Schema is needed for me not for validation, but for reduction in message size mainly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I will use JSON schema will it be saved in binary inside kafka

No. The data will still be UTF-8 encoded JSON.

To reduce data the furthest in the topic, use compression. ZSTD, for example with Avro or Protobuf would be best compressed, with a tradeoff for speed.

You'll need to do your own benchmarks. Related blog - https://blog.cloudflare.com/squeezing-the-firehose/

> implementation from code perspective is kind of bad and overcomplicated (I need to have schema files .avsc,maven plugin to generate avro classes)

This is called schema-first implementation. It's a matter of preference.

If you were building a REST API, you could write the OpenAPI spec first, for example.

> you just need some annotations on POJO and it should just work(looks more something like Jackson

Jackson **also** supports Avro and Protobuf, among other binary formats, such as Smile and MsgPack.

https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-binary

But this library isn't used by the Confluent Serializer classes, so you'd have to use ByteArraySerializer and manually integrate the schema registry on your own.